# Nested for loops to create sections/divs from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I have some nested Json Arrays that I need to display on a website. Essentially I'm exporting hyper V hosts and their vms and want to display them in html.

I'm getting the data out of json fine and is put into a var on my html index in a script tag. (Reason is to avoid needed a web server, long story have work restrictions)

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read the array items and nest loops to display Hyper V's in sections then list their vms as divs within each section.

Here is a cut down version of my imported json data (In my html it's one long string, spaced out here to read easier.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sample =
[
    {
        "host1.domain.com.au":[
            {
                "SERVER1":{
                    "Replication Status":"Nil",
                    "VM Name":"SERVER1",
                    "RAM":8,
                    "CPUs":4,
                    "Hard Drives":128849018880,
                    "IP Address":null
                },
                "SERVER2":{
                    "Replication Status":"Primary",
                    "VM Name":"SERVER2",
                    "RAM":8,
                    "CPUs":4,
                    "Hard Drives":128849018880,
                    "IP Address":null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "host2.domain.com.au":[
            {
                "SERVER3":{
                    "Replication Status":"Primary",
                    "VM Name":"SERVER3",
                    "RAM":8,
                    "CPUs":4,
                    "Hard Drives":107374182400,
                    "IP Address":"10.69.185.113"
                },
                "SERVER4":{
                    "Replication Status":"Primary",
                    "VM Name":"SERVER4",
                    "RAM":8,
                    "CPUs":2,
                    "Hard Drives":64424509440,
                    "IP Address":"10.69.185.25"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
</script>
```

Sample of what I want is:

```
    <section class="hyperv-host">    
        <h1>host1.domain.com.au</h1>
        <div class="vm">
            <h2>SERVER1</h2>
        <div class="vm">
            <h2>SERVER2</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="hyperv-host">    
        <h1>host2.domain.com.au</h1>
        <div class="vm">
            <h2>SERVER3</h2>
        <div class="vm">
            <h2>SERVER4</h2>
    </section>
```

I can get the hosts into sections but it involved created a new array which then didn't have the rest of the data so I couldn't nest a loop inside that. So lost.

Comment: Hey can you post the code that you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Here a very simple example on how this could workout. Sorry for the nested for loops, but it will probably be easier to first understand.

```
var sample =
      [{"host1.domain.com.au":[
          {"SERVER1":{"Replication Status":"Nil","VM Name":"SERVER1","RAM":  8,"CPUs":
                4,"Hard Drives":128849018880,"IP Address":null},
            "SERVER2":{"Replication Status":  "Primary","VM Name":"SERVER2","RAM":
                8,"CPUs":  4,"Hard Drives":  128849018880,"IP Address":  null}}]},
        {"host2.domain.com.au":[
            {"SERVER3":{"Replication Status":  "Primary","VM Name":"SERVER3","RAM":8,"CPUs":4,"Hard Drives":  107374182400,"IP Address":"10.69.185.113"},
              "SERVER4":{"Replication Status":"Primary","VM Name":"SERVER4",
                "RAM":8,"CPUs":2,"Hard Drives":64424509440,"IP Address":
                  "10.69.185.25"}}]
        }];
    var html = '';

    for (var i=0; i < sample.length; i++) {
      var v = sample[i];
      var host_name = Object.keys(v)[0];      
      var html_servers = '';

      for (var i2=0; i2 < v[host_name].length; i2++) {
        var v2 = v[host_name][i2];
        var servers = Object.keys(v2);

        for (var i3=0; i3 < servers.length; i3++) {          
          html_servers += '<div class="vm">'+ servers[i3] +'</div>';
        }
      }

      html +=
        '<section class="hyperv-host">' +
          '<h1>'+ host_name +'</h1>' +
          html_servers +
        '</section>';
    }

    // With html you can use append to some <div> on your html
    console.log(html);
    var e = document.getElementById('id_of_your_element');
    e.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var sample =  [
  {
    "host1.domain.com.au":[
      {
        "SERVER1":{
          "Replication Status":"Nil",
          "VM Name":"SERVER1",
          "RAM":  8,
          "CPUs": 4,
          "Hard Drives":128849018880,
          "IP Address":null
        }
      }
    ],
    "host2.domain.com.au": [
      {
        "SERVER3": {
          "Replication Status":  "Primary",
          "VM Name": "SERVER3",
          "RAM":8,
          "CPUs":4,
          "Hard Drives":  107374182400,
          "IP Address":"10.69.185.113"
        },
        "SERVER4": {
          "Replication Status":"Primary",
          "VM Name":"SERVER4",
          "RAM":8,
          "CPUs":2,
          "Hard Drives":64424509440,
          "IP Address":  "10.69.185.25"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

//This gets each host as a key
const sampleHosts = Object.keys(sample[0]);

//Iterate through every key of the sample
sampleHosts.forEach(function (host) {
  //Create a new section element and give it the right class
  let hostSection = document.createElement("section");
  hostSection.classList.add("hyperv-host");

  //Create a new h1 element and set it's text content to the current host
  let hostHeader = document.createElement("h1");
  hostHeader.textContent = host;

  //Append the header to the newly created section
  hostSection.append(hostHeader);

  //We now grab the servers from the host
  const serverArray = sample[0][host][0];

  //get the rows ready based on the current servers
  const serverRows = makeServersRows(serverArray);

  //From the array we got on the function above, we can iterate through
  serverRows.forEach(function(serverRow) {
    //We just append the rows to the section we created above
     hostSection.append(serverRow);
  });

  //Finally we append the host filled with the server rows to the main body
  document.body.append(hostSection);
});

function makeServersRows(servers) {
  //Servers is an object, so we need to get it's keys again to iterate through it
  const serverKeys = Object.keys(servers);
  //We user map instead of forEach because we want to make a new array based on the values of the servers
  const serverRows = serverKeys.map(function(server) {
    //Create a new div
    let serverDiv = document.createElement("div");
    serverDiv.classList.add("vm");

    //Create a new header
    let serverHeader = document.createElement("h2");
    serverHeader.textContent = server;

    //Put them together
    serverDiv.append(serverHeader);

    //Return each div indiviually to an array outside the .map function
    return serverDiv;
  });

  //Once we have iterated through every server, we return the HTML we created as an array
  return serverRows;
}
```

Some thoughts about this:

- I would try an see if you can reformat the way your sample object is structured, right now you have an array that has 1 and only one object that then has keys inside it with each host, why not do it like this:

  `sample = {"host1.domain": {...}, "host2.domain":  {...}}`
- Same thing for the servers inside each host

I'd also recommend looking into [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to see the reasoning behind this answer!

Comment: Thanks so much will give it a go! My output is like that because I thought that having the hosts in an array would make it better to loop through....
Would it be better to have a "hosts" array so "hosts" is the key then each host has a "vms" array so "vms" is the key with servers as values? so e.g.

`[{"hosts":[{"host1.domain.com.au":[{"vms":[{"SERVER1":`